# Multiple FCM token for single device

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have a Chat application with my own backend server that stores Users detail.
I want to send a notification to an individual User, not individual device, based on FCM token, but here's the problem. FCM token is the same on a single device. so if multiple users want to login with a single device, a single fcm token is gonna saved for multiple users.

this is the rest api I use to send notification.

```
{
    "to": "FCM TOKEN",
    "notification": {
        "title": "TITLE",
        "body": "BODY",
        "mutable_content": true,
        "sound": "Tri-tone"
    },
    "data": {
        "url": "Hello",
        "dl": "<deeplink action on tap of notification>"
    }
}
```

how can I send notification to single user. not the device.

Comment: You always send to a device. If you pass something like a user id with the data, you could use that to determine what you want to do when the notification is received.

Comment: FCM doesn't offer a way to associate device tokens to individual users who might be using your app from multiple devices. You will need to write code to associate a device token to a user account (using whatever you want to make those accounts) by sending that token to your backend, along with the user's ID. Only then can you collect FCM tokens for that user, and message them on any of their devices.